# Using AWS SES API

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I want to access the [AWS SES Webservice](https://email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com) to programmatically add new verified Email identities. The [API reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) does not give the relevant information or at least I can't find it there.

When I try to access the api I get an error due to the missing signature.

```
https://email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com?AWSAccessKeyId=EXAMPLEKeyId&Action=VerifyEmailIdentity&EmailAddress=someone@somewhere.org&Timestamp=2013-04-27T19:30:00Z&Version=2010-12-01&Signature=
```

How do I create this signature exactly, for example using php's hash_hmac()?

Do I need to hash the entire parameters using the SES secret key?

Is there a newer version of the SES API than the one documented (2010-12-01)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should really go through the documentation (again).

Take a look at the [AWS PHP SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/) which would help you a lot.
A sample implementation would be something like:

```
<?php
require 'aws.phar';

use Aws\Common\Enum\Region;
use Aws\Ses\SesClient;


try {   
$ses = SesClient::factory(array(
  'key'    => 'YOUR_KEY',
  'secret' => 'YOUR_SECRET',
  'region' => Region::US_EAST_1
));


$ses->verifyEmailIdentity( array(
    'EmailAddress' => 'the_mail_adress_to_verify@example.com'
));

}
catch( Exception $e )
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. I didn't want to use the sdk and was only following the api documentation. Let's assume I don't use the sdk, because it doesn't exist for the language I want to use. How should I construct those api calls?

Comment: That's easy. Basically you just [authorize and sign your requests](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/query-interface-authentication.html) and when you did that you combine your authorization with the [VerifyEmailIdentity action](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_VerifyEmailIdentity.html) - Other than taking up at least more than five times the amount of code, it should be pretty simple.

Comment: Curious... what language are you wanting to use? There are SDKs for PHP, Ruby, Python, Java, .NET, Node.js, iOS, and Android. You might also be able to take advantage of the AWS CLI (https://github.com/aws/aws-cli) too.

Comment: @JeremyLindblom The question is tagged with PHP - probably the language he wanted to use, then.

Comment: Right, but he mentioned in the first comment that the SDK "doesn't exist for the language I want to use". Just making sure he can find an appropriate tool. Already upvoted your answer.

Comment: @JeremyLindblom Read the comment again; I was to *assume* that there was no SDK for the language he wanted to use, to answer his question.

Comment: Sorry for adding only the php tag. I would use it from php only if needed but would like to use it from smalltalk. Actually there is a package named Cloudfork for Pharo Smalltalk that gave me a hint. It doesn't support SES so that's up to me now. I wanted to understand the basic stuff on how AWS authentication process works.